# Javascript Prompt keeps appearing

Tags: javascript, prompt

The prompt that asks "Enter number of Ounces" keeps reappearing, eve after a value has been entered in the prompt.... What do I do to remove the looping prompt... I just need it to appear once.

```js
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //
            // ******************************
            // Program: LAB3ALT.htm
            // Created by: Tanner DiBella 
            // Date: February 10, 2015
            // Function: Convert Ounces to Pounds
            // *******************************
            //
            /*
            The Ounce to Pounds formula: 1 ounce = 0.0625 pounds
            */

            var i=0;

            while (i<=0) {
                var ounces = prompt("Enter number of Ounces" , "1"); 

                if (ounces==null) { /* Test for cancel */
                    i="1";
                }
                else {
                    var pounds= ounces * 0.0625; /* Compute number of pounds */
                    document.write("<BR>","Ounces : ",ounces);
                    document.write("<BR>","Pounds : ",pounds);
                    document.write("<BR>");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code only sets "i" when the prompt is canceled, so it repeats because "i" will still be 0.

Comment: Note that a better way to do this kind of thing is `while(true) { /* do stuff */ if(needToExitNow) break; /* do more stuff */ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `else`, you  need to set `i>0`. That will do it.

Although, it's quite confusing here. What do you want to do? A simpler version would be,

```
while(true){   //It will repeat indefinitely unlesss you break out of it
    var ounces = prompt("Enter number of Ounces: " , "0");
    if (ounces != null) { //Checks if user cancelled, if yes, it reappears
        var pounds= ounces * 0.0625; /* Compute number of pounds */
        document.write("<BR>","Ounces : ",ounces);
        document.write("<BR>","Pounds : ",pounds);
        document.write("<BR>");
        break;  //when criteria is met, you break out of the loop
    }
}
```

Comment: No. if you set "i=0", "while (i<=0)" will still be true and the loop will continue.

Comment: Ah, you are saying to set `i` to be greater than `0`, not to add `i=0`. Thanks for the clarification.